What do the actual values of Bayesian probabilities mean?
I've been trying to understand the Bayesian interpreration of probability. The common way to explain it (e.g here )seems to be that the number which we assign to a certain proposition designates the level of confidence we have in the truth value of said proposition. But this description is only loosily quantitative.
Say a proposition has a $.67$ probability of being true. What does that mean specifically w.r.t the specific number $.67$, that is, what would be the difference between assigning that number and $.68$ (in the frequentist approach we can define it "operationally" as the limit of the frequence of the population thar verifies the statement, as the population grows larger)?

As you are aware, there is some controversy regarding the meaning of probability in a statement like that.  That said, I am not sure what you are asking.  The difference between $.67$ and $.68$ is that $.68$ is (slightly) larger, so in that case you are (slightly) more confident regarding the proposition.  But, presumably you meant something else?

I think of it this way:  in reality, the given proposition is either true or false, hence the true probability is either $1$ or $0$.  But, we don't know which case holds so we are compelled to estimate the probability given the information we have.  The $.67$ (or $.68$) would then reflect our best estimate of the true probability.  And that estimate is expected to change as we acquire more information.

@lulu I guess I was hoping for an interpretation that reflected some kind of counting, like in the frequencist interpreration. But then, would it be correct to say that Bayesian probabilities hold no meaning in and of itself, but only in relation to each other (vis a vis one is greater than the other and so on and so forth)

I don't understand.  Why "no meaning"?  They represent the best estimate we can make given our state of knowledge, that's hardly nothing.  Sure, sometimes people throw out such numbers based on their feelings, and those estimates tend not to be worth much.  But, other times?  Doctors routinely make probabilistic diagnoses.  Those are based on hard data from "similar" cases.  That gives them some estimates which they then try to sharpen by conducting more tests.  Whether there's a meaningful distinction between $.67, .68$ in that context is a bit unclear, to be sure.

@lulu What I mean is that the only meaning that $.67$ seems to have is that its higher than $.66$ and lower than $.68$. For someone whose only notion of probability was a number that they could assign a concrete "counting" interpretation like "out of a hundred instances, roughly $p$ would come out this way", this is a bit weird

Of course estimating the probability at $p$ means that you expect roughly $p%$ of trials would succeed, though what "trials" means here is not clear.  Sticking with my medical example, if a doctor says a given patient has a certain condition with probability $p$ that means something like "if I look at a number of cases involving broadly similar patients with broadly similar test results, then I would expect that $p%$ of them have the condition."  I don't think there is any mystery here at all.

@lulu But isn't that the same as the frequencist interpretation?

My hypothetical doctor is exercising a great deal of prior knowledge.  "similar" patient is hiding a great deal of professional analysis.  And this doctor plans to toss the estimate out the moment new knowledge is available.  But, as you are suggesting, the differences between the two approaches are not night vs day.
